# Searching Data with Amazon CloudSearch using unique document ID of an individual hit

Tags: php, json, amazon-cloudsearch

is it possible to Search  Data with Amazon CloudSearch using  unique document ID of an individual hit

example:result getting in Json Formate

```
stdClass Object
(
[rank] => -text_relevance
[match-expr] => (label company_name:'Greenline')
[hits] => stdClass Object        
   (
        [found] => 6
        [start] => 0
        [hit] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object                       
                (
                        [id] => ras_csv_693
                        [data] => stdClass Object

                      (
                                [all_us_sic_codes] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => 55719901
                                    )

                                [company_name] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => Greenline Equipment
                                    )

                                [contact_first_name] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => John
                                    )

                                [total_employees] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => 30
                                    )

                            )

                    )
  )
```

Submitting Search Requests in Amazon CloudSearch  like this "http://search-movies-rr2f34ofg56xneuemujamut52i.us-east-1.cloudsearch.
amazonaws.com/2011-02-01/search?bq=company_name:'Greenline'&return-fields=all_us_sic_codes,company_name,contact_first_name,total_employees" i got above example result in json format.

i want to make use of "[id] => ras_csv_693" in example,so by using this "id", searched again like this "2011-02-01/search?q=id:ras_csv_693" but i didnt get any result..
please help me to get result...

Answer (score 7):

Although you asked how to do this in version 2011-02-01, the syntax is sufficiently different in version 2013-01-01, that it's worth showing.

To search for a document by its ID in version 2013-01-01 of the CloudSearch API you use a structured query with `_id:'THE_ID'` as the query. For your example you would request:

[.../2013-01-01/search?q.parser=structured&q=_id:'ras_csv_693'](http://search-movies-rr2f34ofg56xneuemujamut52i.us-east-1.cloudsearch.amazonaws.com/2013-01-01/search?q.parser=structured&q=_id:%27ras_csv_693%27)

Answer (score 3):

You can search by the document ID using: **?bq=docid:'ras_csv_693'**

Example:

```
http://search-movies-rr2f34ofg56xneuemujamut52i.us-east-1.cloudsearch.amazonaws.com/2011-02-01/search?bq=docid:'ras_csv_693'&return-fields=all_us_sic_codes,company_name,contact_first_name,total_employees
```

Note that the URL must be encoded to work, here I'm not encoding just make it easy to understand.